# How can I find 2-tuples with a specific first element in the set of 2-tuples?

Tags: python, set, pattern-matching, tuples

I have a set of pairs with types (str, int). I shall find the tuples that contain specific string and then increment the corresponding integer by 1. I know how to find tuples in a set with asking whether `myTuple in mySet` . But I do not know  the way to handle such situations. I will appreciate any help.

Here is an example set :

```
from sets import Set
up = 2
down = 3
right = 1
left = 2
mySet = Set([("up",up),("down",down),("right",right),("left",left)])
```

Say from `mySet` I want to increment the second of the pair where its first element is `"up"` by 1 so I need something like

```
if ("up",ref) in mySet:
    ref += 1
```

By doing this, I want to increment both the value of the original variable `up` and second element of the tuple.

Comment: Why not to use dictionary for you purpose?

Comment: @Sergey Pugach It seems like dictionary doesn't solve my problem either.

Comment: See the solution of @Sharu below, it seems that dictionary can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a dictionary for your purpose. That way, the re-assignment of the new count would be more clean and easier to interpret. For instance:

```python
>>> my_set = { 'up': 0, 'down': 0, 'left': 0, 'right': 0 }
>>> my_set['up'] += 1
>>> my_set
{'up': 1, 'down': 0, 'left': 0, 'right': 0}
```

As Brian describes, tuples are non-mutable so each time you update the count it has to be created a new one with the updated count. This can then be used to replace the old tuple.

Comment: This makes complete sense to me, a dictionary seems like the stuff he needs here.

Comment: Thank you, also notice that in my example second element of a pair is not a literal but variable.

Comment: @Tripoli, that should work fine. I see that this is resolved know, but yes, you could simply update the counts with the variable references instead of the literal values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filter method to find all entries in the set where your condition, in this case the first entry being "up" is true.

```
subset = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == "up", mySet))
for entry in subset:
    mySet.remove(entry)
    newEntry = (entry[0],(entry[1]+1))
    mySet.add(newEntry)
    up +=1
```

you cannot use `entry+=1` because tuples are non-mutable in python

Comment: Actually, I want to increment both the value of the variable and second element of the tuple.

Comment: by 'the variable' do you mean `up = 2` in your original example?

Comment: Yes, I mean so.

Comment: you can do that as well inside the for loop. I edited my post to include. however this is a rather un-elegant solution because it requires keeping track of the same data in two seperate variables, and this code only works for the up case, not any other, without changing the up+=1 line to a different varaible each time